# Div height by percentage with an auto height parent

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use relative (in percentage) heights on all my divs based to the height of the screen. Problem is that I'm using an auto-height container element. Is there any way to use relative sizes on divs and still have an automatic height on my parent div. Everything works as expected if i'll set the height of the container to 100%, but i'll need it to expand by it's content.

This is basically how i've set things up now:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body, html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.container {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
.element1 {
height: 15%;
width: 80%;
}
.element2 {
height: 25%;
width: 80%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="element1">Some text here</div>
    <div class="element2">Some stuff here</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot. A parent with a height value of `auto` means the parent will extend to contain all its children - therefore the container's height is dependent on its children's height.

If the children have a height relative to their parent, their height is dependent on the parent's height.

This circular dependency prevents you from doing what you describe.

Comment: True, if tried some possible workarounds, but you can't fix this with pure HTML/ CSS.

Comment: True, using Javascript you can calculate the height of all the children and dynamically apply it to the parent as a constant.

Comment: That's pretty much what I expected. That would be great if you could just use a specific element as a parent (for example body in this situation) instead of the one that actually is the last element before the child. If anyone knows a good javascript implemention of this, that would do the trick as well. My js skills are very limited so i can't figure one out myself.